# Realm DB going nuts in Android

Tags: java, android, realm

So I have the following problem:

```
    if (!realm.isClosed()){
        Log.d("PROVIDER realm not clsd", "closing now");
        realm.executeTransaction((t)->realm.close());
    }
```

and this throws exception. Here it is:

```
D/PROVIDER realm not clsd: closing now
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3047)
```

Now how the hell is `"Realm instance has already been closed"`, when `realm.isClosed()==false` ?

Comment: You closed the realm inside a transaction, in order to finish the transaction, it must be open. I don't think you need to place it inside a transaction in order to close it.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: Since that solved your problem I'll post an answer and ask you to kindly accept it.

Comment: Go on :) ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment that you check `realm.isClosed()` it is not closed indeed. However, you have opened a transaction which, in order to complete, still needs that realm instance to be open. The problem is, you're closing this instance inside the transaction. **Simple solution**: remove `realm.close()` from inside the transaction, it doesn't need to be in one.